# Calculus Proof of An Example of Exponential Distribution Memoryless Property

Tags: exponential-distribution

> $E[X^2|X>1] = E[(X+1)^2]$
>
> By the memoryless property, the conditional distribution of $X$, given that $X>1$, is the same as the unconditional distribution of $X+1$. Therefore, the equation stands.

I'm trying to prove $$P(X|X>1) = P(X+1)$$ as given in the statement. However, the equation doesn't come as true according to my calculation. Please let me know where my mistake is. Here is my calculation:

$\begin{align}P(X|X>1) &= \frac{P(X=k)}{P(X>1)}  , \quad k>1\\
&= \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda k}}{e^{-\lambda}}\\
&= \lambda e^{-\lambda k + 1},\quad k>1
\end{align}
$

$\begin{align}P(X+1) &= \lambda e^{-\lambda (x+1)}\\
&= \lambda e^{-\lambda x - \lambda }
\end{align}
$

Comment: Your tag and title mention it, but you may want to say $X$ is an exponential distribution and state the mean of the distribution.

Comment: it depends on the distribution of $X$. You are assuming that $X$ is discrete writing $P(X=k|X>1)$. Moreover: what means $P(X|X>1)$? Probably you wanted to write $P(X=k|X>1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we really want to prove is, for $k\ge1$ (since it is trivial when $k<1$),
$$P(X=k|X>1) = P(X+1=k)$$
which expands into
$$\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda k}}{e^{-\lambda}}=\lambda e^{-\lambda(k-1)}$$
Simplifying the LHS leads to the RHS, proving the identity:
$$\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda k}}{e^{-\lambda}}=\lambda e^{-\lambda k-\lambda}=e^{-\lambda(k-1)}$$